# Como inserir uma List<> em uma Listview C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Estou tentando inserir uma `List<>` (Gerada por outra classe que traz os dados do Banco), os dados chegam a ser inseridos porém a `ListView` só recebe a primeira coluna, e a outra fica com valor nulo.

Abaixo está o código do `form` onde está inserido a `ListView`, tentei algo com o `foreach` mas também não obtive sucesso

```
private void Form_Usuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    UsuarioDAO usuario = new UsuarioDAO();
    usuarios = usuario.MostrarUsuarios().ToList();
    foreach(var item in usuarios)
    {
        listViewUsuarios.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { item.Nome}));
    }  
}
```

Resultado:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não se coloca a solução na pergunta e sim na resposta vou reverter isso e você coloque como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Como inserir itens em um componente [ListView do Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netcore-3.1)?

No seu método `ListViewData.Items.Add` aceita uma instância da classe [ListViewItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netcore-3.1) que deve ser carregado com as informações contidas em uma lista de valores, um exemplo básico e manual:

```
ListViewData.Items.Clear();
var item0 = new ListViewItem();
item0.Text = "pt.stackoverflow.com";
item0.SubItems.Add("Site");

var item1 = new ListViewItem();
item1.Text = "microsoft.com";
item1.SubItems.Add("Site");

ListViewData.Items.Add(item0);
ListViewData.Items.Add(item1);
```

onde a primeira coluna do seu [ListViewItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netcore-3.1) na propriedade `Text` é o valor da primeira coluna da lista retornada, e as demais são `SubItems` que com o método `Add` e adicionado os próximo texto da próxima coluna e assim sucessivamente, a figura representa o código:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para cada coluna a ser adicionado mais um `SubItems.Add` precisa ser invocado e assim sucessivamente para ser carregados todos os itens dessa coluna.

No seu código é algo assim:

```
private void Form_Usuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    UsuarioDAO usuario = new UsuarioDAO();
    List<Usuario> usuarios = usuario.MostrarUsuarios().ToList();
    foreach(var item in usuarios)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = item.Nome;
        item.SubItems.Add(item.Cargo);
        listViewUsuarios.Items.Add(item);
    }  
}
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [ListView Classe](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netcore-3.1)
- [ListView.View Propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.view?view=netcore-3.1)
- [C# - Usando ListView para exibição de dados - Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/c_lstv1.htm)
- [Listview Details view not displaying anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451487/listview-details-view-not-displaying-anything)
- [ListView in C# - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/working-with-listview-in-C-Sharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui aqui pessoal, abaixo está o código com as alterações que fiz para o código funcionar.

```
private void Form_Usuarios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
    UsuarioDAO usuario = new UsuarioDAO();
    usuarios = usuario.MostrarUsuarios().ToList();  
    foreach(var item in usuarios)
    {
        ListViewItem lv1 = new ListViewItem(item.Nome);
        lv1.SubItems.Add(item.Cargo);
        listViewUsuarios.Items.Add(lv1);            
    }  
}
```

Comment: o alinhamento do texto no formato código é importante, verifique isso na hora de posta.

Comment: se esse retorno `usuario.MostrarUsuarios().ToList();` retornar um `List<Usuario>` porque antes você cria uma instância que é desnecessaria? dá uma olhada no código que eu implementei. Cuidado com os códigos desnecessários na codificação e instâncias sem necessidade é também um problema.